# Can clion use arrow(->) not dot(.) to access struct member when extracting methods?

Tags: refactoring, clion

Original Code:

```c
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

int main() {
    Point point = {1, 2};

    printf("%d %d\n", point.x, point.y);
    return 0;
}
```

Use refactor to extract a method:

```c
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

void PrintPoint(Point *point)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", (*point).x, (*point).y);
}

int main() {
    Point point = {1, 2};

    PrintPoint(&point);
    return 0;
}
```

But I want the generated PrintPoint function is like this:

```c
void PrintPoint(Point *point)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", point->x, point->y);
}
```

Is there a configuration in CLion to change `(*pStru).` to `pStru->` when extracting a method?

Comment: I think the `C` tag have nothing to do with a question.

Comment: OK, remove the c tag. Actually, I mean the C language.

Comment: The question is not about a programming task that is somehow solved in `C`. It is about particular IDE.

Comment: Yes, It is about the clion IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to configure the behaviour. There is a bug in CLion tracker about your case. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2193
Maybe it's time to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, now I can give up looking for a configuration like this. I hope this problem will be solved in the new version.